# Identify a book - young adult, unable to interact with physical objects, Mars poster

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, mars

I encountered this book about thirty years ago at school. It was probably a young adult novel rather than anything more serious and I think it was not part of any series.

The details are:

- A boy finds himself progressively unable to interact with physical objects, slowly moving away from his physical reality into an alternate reality.
- There was a mosaic poster of Mars made from images returned by Viking featured as well.

**What is the name of this book?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was it [Lee Harding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Harding_(writer))'s '[Displaced Person](http://www.middlemiss.org/lit/authors/hardingl/displacedp.html)' (1979)? It involves a boy who is progressively unable to interact with the world.

[Goodreads link](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2223038.Displaced_Person)

> Graeme Drury is seventeen. He is rather an ordinary-looking person of average height. He dresses casually and well and gets along fine with his classmates and friends. In fact the typical all-rounder.
>
> The change begins gradually. More and more he feels that people are ignoring him. Why? Waitresses, tram conductors, even his parents and girl friend, are looking right through him as if they can hardly see or hear him.
>
> And as he becomes indistinct to them, they and their world become grey and faint to him. Is he going mad? What's going on?

I don't clearly remember the Viking Mars images poster being mentioned though.

Comment: That's it, I remember the cover now - thanks.